# Integration of exponential function having limits upto infinity

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

I am just stuck with this problem:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\mathrm{e}^{x/a} - \mathrm{e}^{b/x} \over x}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
It is also given that $ab$ is not equal to $0$.

Comment: You need to add more context to your problem.

Comment: Actually, your integral doesn't converge.

Comment: Yes it seems to me also. I think there should be some other terms also.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by other terms.

Comment: May be you mean $$\int^{b}_{a}\frac{e^{\frac{x}{a}}-e^{\frac{b}{x}}}{x}dx$$, Then  answer is $=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See that

$$x\to\infty\implies\frac{e^{x/a}-e^{b/x}}x\to\infty$$

So that the integral cannot converge.

Similarly,

$$x\to0^+\implies\frac{e^{x/a}-e^{b/x}}x\to-\infty$$

In other words, theres all sorts of things preventing this integral from being evaluable.